# Drawer navigation in react navigation will not close until the next page appear

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I don't know if I am the one getting it wrong. I am working on a project,  I use react navigation, and I am using drawer and stack navigator. But when I click on any menu on the drawer 1. The drawer will remain open until the next page appear 2. The menu that I click will remain active until the next screen appear.

I try to check other application performance,  they don't perform like that. Is that how react navigation works or am I the one getting it wrong?

Please help because I am new to react native and react navigation.

Comment: Show us the relevant code.

Comment: const DrawerStack = DrawerNavigator({
 

  NotePad: {
    screen: NotePad,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: "NotePad"
    }
  },
  Home: {
     screen: HomeScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: "Home"
    }
  },})

Comment: but when i click on any of the drawer menu , the next page will be visible before the drawer close.

and again even if am making  request to the server in the next page , everything will have been concluded before the drawer will close

Answer (score 0):

i came across a post on [Fixing common performance problems in React Navigation](https://novemberfive.co/blog/react-performance-navigation-animations/)

i just change the code in componentdidmount method like this

```
 componentDidMount(){
InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => {
 // Component is done animating
  //  Start making any request


});
```

};

with that my problem is solved but i dont know if is the right way of doing it.